# Windows pop up message when responds to ping [cmd, PowerShell]

Tags: powershell, cmd, ip, ping, msg

Is it possible to run a specific script and receive a message (like msg command) when the pinged machine becomes available?

```
ping -n <Address> | find "TTL=" && (
msg * Online
)
```

Comment: Why not use a simple batch file with a label looping mechanism! 1. ```:loop```, 2.```@ping.exe -n <address> 2>nul | find.exe "TTL=" 1>nul && (msg.exe * Online) || goto loop```. If you wanted to reduce the frequency of checks, to say every 3 seconds, change ```goto loop``` to ```timeout.exe /t 3 /nobreak 1>nul & goto loop```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a PowerShell way:

```sh
ping -t <Address> | Select-String 'TTL=' | Select-Object -First 1
msg * Online
```

- `ping -t <Address>` repeatedly pings the given host.
- `Select-String 'TTL='` searches each output line of `ping` for the given RegEx pattern. If found, it is piped to the next command.
- `Select-Object -First 1` ends the pipeline as soon as the first line has been found.
- This outputs the line containing "TTL=" to the console. If you don't want this, append `| Out-Null`.